# iphone right margin

Tags: iphone, css, ipad

A wide right margin appears in iphone, all the content is visible. When I slide a there is a wide right
gap, how can I fix this issue.

I am using

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

@media screen and  (max-width: 480px) {

```
body{
    width:100% !important;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:#1d1d1d;
    outline: 1px solid palegreen;
}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something on you page that is sticking out on the right side. You can use inspect element, or 3d view on the inspect element in Firefox to figure out what element it is, and then decrease its width, or adjust its `display` rule.

Comment: outline: 1px solid palegreen; all the elements are within this line

Comment: Did you view it in firefox 3d view, because there is definitely something causing the iPhone to have a gap on the right.